# Dynamically nest results in object from fs directory walk

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Reading a bunch of translation files in a file directory and assigning the data to a global object so that I can pull a translation using `i18nContent.messages.en.9999`

File tree is like this

```
locales
    messages
        en.json => {"9999": "Unexpected Error", "0": "Success"}
        de.json => {"9999": "German Error", "0": "German Success"}
    emails
       en.json => {"signupEmail": "Thanks for signing up", "passwordEmail": "Password changed"}
       de.json => {"signupEmail": "German signing up", "passwordEmail": "German Password changed"}
```

I am able to get all of the "names" for each of the nested objects. However, I am unable to assemble the total object during the directory walk.

ATTEMPT 1

```
global.i18nContent = {};

walkDir(dir, function (filePath, dir) {
  if (filePath.substr(-5) === ".json") {
    let directory = dir.split(/[\s\/]+/);
    directory = directory[directory.length - 1];

    let lang = filePath.split(/[\s\/]+/);
    lang = lang[lang.length - 1].substr(-7, 2);

    //this substr fix is to make this work on Macs
    let rem = __dirname.toString().substr(0, __dirname.toString().length - 3);

    let langFolder = {};
    langFolder[lang] = require(filePath.replace(rem, '../'));

    Object.assign(i18nContent[directory], langFolder);
  }
});
```

ATTEMPT 2

Removed

```
let langFolder = {};
langFolder[lang] = require(filePath.replace(rem, '../'));

Object.assign(i18nContent[directory], langFolder);
```

and just tried `i18nContent[directory][lang] = require(filePath.replace(rem, '../'))` or `i18nContent[directory[lang]] = require(filePath.replace(rem, '../'))`

console output is showing `['undefined']`

Should be nested to reference like `i18nContent.messages.en.9999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using [walkdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walkdir), right? Then I would just do it like this:

```
global.i18nContent = {};
const emitter = walkDir(yourDir);

emitter.on('file', filename => {
  const parts = filename.match(/^.*\/locales\/(\w*)\/(\w*)\.json$/);

  if (!parts) return;
  const [, folderName, lang] = parts;

  if (!global.i18nContent[folderName]) global.i18nContent[folderName] = {};
  global.i18nContent[folderName][lang] = require(filename);
});
```

Comment: actually I was using a home-grown version of walkDir, but i'll check this out. thanks!